# inner_join in R using dplyr is shifting the non-"by" value up one row

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two tables in dplyr with data, and a third table specifying a 1-to-1 mapping between rows in those tables. I wanted to pull out only records from the two data tables with entries in the 1-to-1 mapping table so I can compare the results from the two data tables directly against one another (they are not in the same order and some rows do not have corresponding entries in the other data table). I tried to do this with inner_joins between my data tables and my mapping table, but it seems to be missing a single row each time, specifically, the first row. It seems to be shifting the second, non-"by" value up one row in the join. Here's some output that should be helpful:

```
>PA14ortho #the 1-to-1 mapping table
Source: local data frame [5,366 x 2]

   PAO1.id    PA14.id
1   PA0001 PA14_00010
2   PA0002 PA14_00020
3   PA0003 PA14_00030
4   PA0004 PA14_00050
..     ...        ...
> select(PA14.3rep.res, PA14.id) #the "label" row in my first data table
Source: local data frame [5,977 x 1]

      PA14.id
1  PA14_00010
2  PA14_00020
3  PA14_00030
4  PA14_00050
..        ...
> inner_join(PA14.3rep.res, PA14ortho, by="PA14.id") %>% select(PA14.id, PAO1.id) #the results of the inner join, note how there's one less record and that PAO1.id has shifted up one
Source: local data frame [5,365 x 2]

      PA14.id PAO1.id
1  PA14_00010  PA0002
2  PA14_00020  PA0003
3  PA14_00030  PA0004
4  PA14_00050  PA0005
..        ...     ...
> select(PAO1.3rep.res, PAO1.id) #the second data table
Source: local data frame [5,606 x 1]

   PAO1.id
1   PA0001
2   PA0002
3   PA0003
4   PA0004
..     ...
> inner_join(PAO1.3rep.res, PA14ortho, by="PAO1.id") %>% select(PAO1.id, PA14.id) #the same thing happens - the non-"by" row is shifted up one
Source: local data frame [5,365 x 2]

   PAO1.id    PA14.id
1   PA0001 PA14_00020
2   PA0002 PA14_00030
3   PA0003 PA14_00050
4   PA0004 PA14_00060
..     ...        ...
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I used `merge` out of base and it worked fine, so I suppose this question has turned more into a bug report than anything! (i.e.
`tbl_df(merge(PA14.3rep.res, PA14ortho, by="PA14.id")) %>% select(PA14.id, PAO1.id)` looks like you'd expect).

Comment: Can you please file a reproducible example on the dplyr issue tracker?

Comment: I'd be happy to - is that on your github?

Comment: Yup: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/